# YII Inventory Control system issue

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii, inventory-management

Guys help me to do this. I'm new to YII. I want to display each item branches stock like this.

[image]

actual database

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Here is some documentation to help you http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

Comment: i read this but my issue is different

Comment: Mohit I'dont know how to do it...do i need this values to be stored in a array or is there another way..

Comment: Do you always have 4 branches, or is the number of branches dynamic?

Comment: yes its dynamic...for now its 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cross tab or pivot table.  Here is a link: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523

Comment: yes this is what i want,but how to do it in yii active record

Comment: Active record is convenient way of accessing and modifying objects, but can't do everything. Perhaps [use DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao)?

Comment: You are going to have to write your own SQL.  to display the results in a grid you will need to use CSqlDataProvider. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for the same thing and have a solution using CSqlDataProvider. It is important to note when using CSqlDataProvider it returns an array unlike CActiveDataProvider which returns an object.

Here is the model code

```
public function displayStock($id)
{
    $sql='SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) as productCount FROM stock WHERE assigned_to = 2 GROUP BY product_id';
    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(


        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
    ));
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Here is the code for the veiw

```
$stockDataProvider = Stock::model()->displayStock(Yii::app()->user->id);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'stock-grid',
    'ajaxUpdate' => true,
    'template'=>'{items}{summary}{pager}',
    'dataProvider'=>$stockDataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(

        'product_id',
        array(
                'name'=>'test',
                'value'=>'$data["productCount"]'
            ),


        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{view} {update}',

        ),

    ),
));
```

When defining the SQL statement in the model, you can see we have set the COUNT(*) to be called productCount. Then in the view we reference that name in the columns array like so

```
array(
                'name'=>'test',
                'value'=>'$data["productCount"]'
            ),
```

So simply replace productCount with the name you have used.

I'm sure the above code could do with some tweaking ie using Binded params in the query etc, but this has worked for me.

Any comments or improvements are very welcome. I'm only about 8 months into php and 3 months into yii.